# Start Activity in TabActivity1 from TabActivity2

Tags: android, android-activity, tabactivity

So in my application I'm using two different Tabhosts.Here is an example

TABHOST1 Contains :

TAB1  | TAB2 | TAB3 | TAB4 | TAB5

TABHOST2 Contanins :

TB1 | TB2 | TB3 | TB4 | TB5

TAB2 - Activity 1

TB2 - Activity 2

So basically I want to start Activity 2, using Activity 1.The both activities are in different TABHOSTS so I need to keep the TABHOST2 when I start Activity 2,from Activity 1 (which is in TABHOST1).

Any suggestions how can I do that?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the selected tab index from `Activity1` While starting `Activity2` from `Activity1`

```
Intent in = new Intent(this, TABHOSTS2.class); //TABHOSTS2 or whatever your second TabActivity is. 
in.putExtra("SelectedTab", 1);
startActivity(in);
```

and in you `TABHOSTS2` which will be `TabActivity`, do something like:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabs); 
    //set you Tabs and blah blah

    int selectedTab = getIntent().getIntExtra("SelectedTab", 0);
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(selectedTab);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way I can kill TABHOST2 clickin by TB5,without creating a new class as a content of TB5 and call finish()?Just clickin the tab

Answer (score 0):

to start activity2 all you need to do is startActivity , no need for tabhost 2 .
if your problem is how to keep child activity ( activity 2 in your case ) inside tabhost , go through ActivityGroup doc ,which will guide you about nested activities inside tabHost